# Clashing reverse accessors and queries in Django for many to many field?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, orm

```
from django.db import models


class Appointment(models.Model):
    doctors = models.ManyToManyField('Doctor', through='AppointmentAccess', related_name='appointments')


class Doctor(models.Model):
    appointments = models.ManyToManyField('Appointment', through='AppointmentAccess', related_name='doctors')
```

I get the following error:

```
core.Appointments.doctors: (fields.E302) Reverse accessor for 'PatientProfile.users' clashes with field name 'Doctor.appointments'.
        HINT: Rename field 'Doctor.appointments', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'Appointment.doctors'.
core.Appointment.doctors: (fields.E303) Reverse query name for 'Doctor.appointments' clashes with field name 'Appointment.doctors'.
        HINT: Rename field 'Doctor.appointments', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'Appointment.doctors'.
core.Doctor.appointments: (fields.E302) Reverse accessor for 'Doctor.appointments' clashes with field name 'Appointments.doctors'.
        HINT: Rename field 'Appointment.doctors', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'Doctor.appointments'.
core.User.patient_profiles: (fields.E303) Reverse query name for 'Doctor.appointments' clashes with field name 'Appointments.doctors'.
        HINT: Rename field 'Appointments.doctors', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'Doctor.appointments'.
```

Why? Can someone help me understand this error? The many to many field should be kept track of through the AppointmentAccess table instead of generating a new intermediary table. How does the related name appointments clash with doctors?

Comment: Why do you need to specify the m2m in both the models? Just specify it in one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying the many to many relationship in both the models. This is not needed as Django automatically adds a reverse relation to the other model in the relation, so you can simply write:

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    # Remove below line
    doctors = models.ManyToManyField('Doctor', through='AppointmentAccess', related_name='appointments')
    ...


class Doctor(models.Model):
    appointments = models.ManyToManyField('Appointment', through='AppointmentAccess', related_name='doctors')
```

Now since you have already set the `related_name` (if you hadn't the default would have been `doctor_set`, i.e. the model name in lowercase) if you have an instance of `Appointment` as `appointment` you can simply write:

```
for doctor in appointment.doctors.all():
    print(doctor)
```